# What does this star symbol mean in Pokemon X Pokedex

Tags: pokemon-x-y

What initially caught my eye about this Pancham is that he was brown instead of black like other Panchams. I figured there must be a reason so I caught him but I'm not sure what's different about him. He also has a red star symbol that none of me other Pokemon have. Is this a "Shiny"?

[image]

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but that's probably just the marking you selected for it.  It's an extra method of organization.

Comment: @fbueckert No, if he had selected the star, the star near the heart and diamond would be black. Confusing that they use the same symbol, tho.

Comment: @fbueckert I definitely didn't mark it but it does look that way. The colour is also suspicious though.

Comment: The red star on the left is characteristic for shiny Pokémon. I know it, because I used to play with cheats and Action Replay a lot when playing with Pearl.

Comment: You are a lucky person! You came across a shiny, which is a 1/8000 chance to appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on this video

, that does appear to be a shiny pancham. Congratulations. If you want to be sure, shinies apparently sparkle when you send them into battle as shown in the video

[This thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67477350) also indicates that the shiny pancham is brown.

[Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon) confirms that the star indicates that the Pokemon is shiny.

Comment: Thanks for the sparkle in battle confirmation info. It's a shiny. That's awesome, rare you get a shiny of a Pokemon you like. I can't mark as answered just yet.

Comment: Why was all this info so hard to Google? Thank you.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen Because getting a shiny Pokémon is extremely rare. Most people don't even know they exist and when they do encounter them, they either don't realize it or write it off as a virus (a cousin of mine even deleted her save, believing it had gotten corrupted after encountering a shiny Pokémon). Similarly unknown would be [Pokérus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokerus).

Comment: I didn't find it hard to google at all. All that information came from just googling "shiny pancham"

Comment: @Lawton that's only because you *knew* it was shiny and therefore knew what to search for. Searching for a random star symbol on the stats page of a pokemon is much more difficult.

Comment: @shanodin Well, the term shiny was in the question so unless someone edited it he was aware that they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that's a shiny! Congratulations, they're incredibly rare!

Answer (score 2):

The red star means it's a shiny.

That mark has been carried forward from Black/White/Black 2 and White 2. I can confirm, as for these games I:

- Pokétransferred a shiny from Diamond and
- Caught shiny Haxorus, Gibble, Dratini.

Another way to tell, the Pokédex number on the summary turns red, further confirming it's a shiny Pokémon.

Since I haven't seen any shiny so far in my Y game, and the picture the OP has uploaded doesn't show it, I can't tell if the Pokédex number shown on the summary also changes its color (if you're looking at a shiny Pokémon in this generation).

Comment: Hi RegaliaX, welcome to Arqade! This space is reserved for answers, so I removed the part about the blue dot. You can ask that as another question if you want, just click the 'Ask Question' button on the top right of the page :).

Comment: Doesn't look like the number is any different colour