# How can I tell in battle if a Pokemon is shiny?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I haven't caught one yet, so I wouldn't know, but how do you identify a shiny Pokemon vs non-shiny?

I remember that in previous gens, the Pokemon would sparkle before battling, is there any way I can know if the Pokemon is shiny or not (in battle, not in profile)?

Comment: Related: [What does this star symbol mean in Pokemon X Pokedex?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135703/what-does-this-star-symbol-mean-in-pokemon-x-pokedex)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three things:

- The pokemon will be coloured differently. For some pokemon, this can be a drastic change, while others there can be a very mild difference.
- When the pokemon enters battle, a little sparkling animation will occur, along with a unique sound. Blue stars will come out of the pokemon.
- In the pokemon interface, there will be a red star near the markings to indicate that the pokemon is shiny.

Comment: This sound will be very characteristic :) I can tell as a new owner of shiny Pidgey

Comment: I'll have to double-check, but I believe you can't run from shiny Pokemon.

Comment: @Yuki Don't think that's true... It's just like a normal pokemon except a different colour

Comment: @Yuki Shiny Pokemon can be run from, can faint, can do whatever you can think of that a normal Pokemon can. Shiny only have a different colourset.

Answer (score 3):

Shiny Pokémon are characterized by not only the different colors, but also the sparkling animation made when is is first sent out or appears. The odds of finding a Shiny Pokémon are next to nothing, but what's harder to find? Shiny Super-Sized Pumpkaboo/Gourgeist with Insomnia. Also, if you completely fill the Pokédex, you will get the Shiny Charm, which increases the odds of finding a Shiny Pokémon.

Answer (score 2):

If a pokemon is shiny, it will sparkle at the beginning of battle, and the pokemon will have a different color than a non-shiny pokemon.

Shiny pokemon have a better chance of appearing in the friend safari. I found about 3 shiny pokemon in the friend safari after encountering about 20 pokemon.

Comment: For future reference, that was pure luck. The odds that you get 3 shiny Pokemon are extremely low. Even with shiny charm, Friend Safari and your lucky socks on. It is absolutely true that you have a better chance in the FS, but 3 in 20 is just extreme. Lucky you!

Answer (score 1):

The Pokemon will be a different colour and it will sparkle with and stars will come out of the Pokemon's body. Quick tip: Shiny Pokemon aren't stronger then normal Pokemon they are just coloured differently and stars come out of their bodies. Also, some event shiny Pokemon might be shinies but with good IVs but it might seem strong. It's just the IVs.