# How can I tell a Pokemon is a shiny in Pokemon Sun/Moon specifically?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

The exact question here just with a different game in the series: [How can I tell in battle if a Pokemon is shiny?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136133/how-can-i-tell-in-battle-if-a-pokemon-is-shiny)

Except for Pokemon Sun and Moon. How can I tell a Pokemon is a shiny? Is there anything special in this game that is different than the others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell in battle if a Pokemon is shiny?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136133/how-can-i-tell-in-battle-if-a-pokemon-is-shiny)

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta No.  Different games.

Comment: But the answer is the same.

Comment: stuff like this typically doesn't change between pokemon generations. game freak is very, very conservative about making changes to core mechanics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Old indicators of shininess still apply, colouration as well as the battle animation as discussed on the linked question. The only change will be with the new interface.

There is still a red star at the lower left to indicate shininess, just below the Pokemon's sprite. This is on the lower screen of the DS, at the Pokemon summary screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the question seemed to ask for in battle specifically: 
You REALLY just gotta give 'em a good look. Most shiny forms are clearly differently coloured, but there are those that are just SLIGHTLY different (Looking at you, Pichu) so you really have to pay attention. Also, in previous games they would sparkle when popping up for the first time, I just hope they kept that? 
So yeah, no clear indicator in battle, no little star besides its name unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I just caught my first shiny, and I noticed that while the battle screen commences, there is a visible star that appears in the animation to indicate shininess.

Answer (score -3):

I started my game off with a shiny Popplio and it actually has a star by its sprite. Other than that, they look a whole lot different a Pokémon's normal form.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that wasn't already said in the accepted answer.

Comment: Not all shiny Pokémon look significantly different from their non-shiny counterparts. As already mentioned, the other half of your answer adds nothing new.