# Why does my Pokemon have a star appear every time I use it?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have a Magby  that I caught and every time I bring it out in battle, a star appears on it. What does that mean? It doesn't happen for any other Pokemon I have.

Comment: Is your Magby red or orange-ish?

Comment: I'd say he's more orange than red. He was the first one I've seen, and I caught him in the wild

Comment: How appropriate that your name is Ash and that you caught a rare pokemon without realising its significance

Comment: You could include a screenshot. I bet people would like to see it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your Magby is shiny. Congratulations!

A shiny Pokémon is a rare (1/4096) colour variant version, and displays a little star when it's sent out in battle. Other than that, there is no difference between a shiny Pokémon and its normal counterpart.

To confirm this, you can check your Magby's status page, you should see a [red star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291902/143571) near its model.

Answer (score 9):

Your Magby is a rare alternate color Pokémon, also known as a [Shiny Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon). Congrats on catching one!

Shiny Pokémon have a different appearance, but are otherwise the same as their regular counterparts. Aside from the alternate color, you know that they are Shiny because they have a sparkle when they come out and a star on their status screen.  [image: Shiny Star]

In Generation 7, the odds of finding a Shiny Pokémon in the wild is 1 out of 4096. The Pokémon company [has written a guide on SOS chaining](http://www.pokemon.com/us/strategy/special-pokemon-answer-the-call-for-help-in-sos-battles/) indicating that the odds of finding a shiny Pokémon increase in SOS Battles the more wild Pokémon are called. You have to have a whopping 70 Pokémon get called into the battle before you get the best odds: 1 out of 1024. [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/294110/47878) on the site has more information about the odds.

You can also increase your odds by getting the Shiny Charm, which you can find at the GAME FREAK office in Heahea City after you complete your Pokédex.

Usually, only player-obtainable Pokémon are Shiny. Earlier games had some trainers in battle facilities (e.g. Battle Frontier) that had Shiny Pokemon. *Sun* and *Moon* introduced the first trainer outside of that with a Shiny Pokémon: Sightseer Marcus in Seafolk Village and his Exeggcute. So you'll never see a gym leader suddenly come out with a Shiny Pokémon.

### Regular Magby

[image: Regular Magby]

### Shiny Magby

[image: Shiny Magby]

Comment: The information about SOS battles is incorrect or at least simplified, and trainers had shiny Pokémon back in FRLG's Trainer Tower.

Comment: Additionally, it might be a good idea to mention that the red star is only shown on the Pokémon's status screen and not in battle. It is also not shown near the Pokémon's name but next to their marks.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I've corrected the part about trainers: Sun & Moon has the first trainer outside of a battle facility. I'm not sure what is incorrect about SOS battles; that is my reading of the Gen 7 section of the Bulbapedia article.

Comment: [According to this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/294110/143571), the 1/1024 figure is only a maximum chance obtainable after a long chain, which is in line with how chaining has worked in previous generations.

Comment: It's also slightly misleading to mention that only wild Pokèmon can be shiny, with things like starters and Type: Null, but it's really minor.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I've corrected the SOS battle info with some info from the Pokémon Company's new guide

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Also changed "Wild Pokémon" to "player-obtainable Pokémon" because you're right, starters and event Pokémon can be shiny.